# Phone stays connected to WiFi even when out of reach

Tags: wi-fi, asus-zenfone

As the title says, when I get out of home, my phone keeps the connection to my Wi-Fi even when it is out of reach. This results in a Wi-Fi icon with an "X" and thus not using mobile data and not having internet.

Normally when I get out of home it usually disconnects the Wi-Fi and switches on mobile data, but now I need to disable / enable the Wi-Fi so it disconnects and have access to internet again. Any ideas ?

Phone is Asus Zenfone 9 with Android 13

Comment: May help-in developer options enable wifi scan throttling

Comment: Does the Wifi come back when you return home? I would try to reset the Wifi chip by shutting down the phone completely and keep it of for a minute or two (not reboot, really shut down).

Comment: @Robert Yes it comes back, but rebooting the phone does not change anything since it ran out of battery yesterday and the problem persists

Comment: @beeshyams Already on

Comment: My guess is that the "Direct wifi" option is enabled but not sure. Maybe you could try another wifi or SSID to make sure it's not a bug.
Do you know when or why the phone does not behave as it used to ?

Comment: @beeshyams I think you misunderstood, my problem is not that it won't connect, my problem is that I can be 10 km away from my wifi (literally), and the phone still keeps that connection even out of reach, instead of switching to mobile data

Comment: Well... If I knew why, I would not post the question :) Wi-Fi direct is not enabled, and that happened just after moving out in my new home with a new router if that can help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would try two things

1. Forget that Wifi connection and then connect again.
2. If that doesnt work then reset network settings.

[image] [image]

Comment: Tried it and it seems that it resolved the issue, many thanks but still wondering why that happened...